# What could cause dropdowns to keep their selected values on full page refresh (F5) in Firefox but not IE?

Tags: firefox, page-refresh, browser-refresh

What could cause dropdowns to keep their selected values on full page refresh (F5) in Firefox but not IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firefox likes to cache select box values. Do a hard refresh to reset them (Ctrl + F5)